# Run Vagrant Terminal As Sublime Repl on Windows Box

Tags: windows, ssh, sublimetext2, vagrant, read-eval-print-loop

I have a web environment with Vagrant currently running on my local machine.  What I'd like to do is to run that Vagrant development environment as a repl in Sublime.

I have Sublime Repl installed, and I edited the shell configuration file to call `ssh.exe`, but I keep getting errors.

I figured out I needed to run `ssh -t -t` to force `ssh` to run in a virtual terminal.  However, I now get the following error when I try to execute:

```
    Permission denied, please try again.
    Permission denied, please try again.
    Permission denied (publickey,password).

    ***Repl Closed***
```

I also get the same error when trying to execute the code in the `cmd.exe` repl that is already configured.

The line of code in Vagrant Main.sublime-menu file that that is getting executed is:
        "windows": ["ssh", "-t", "-t", "-p", "2222", "vagrant:vagrant@127.0.0.1"]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.  For anyone else looking to do this, I figured out how.

I did it using `plink.exe` with my already existing `putty.exe` saved session.  I created a configuration folder for Vagrant in the Sublime REPL plugin folder located in `Data\Packages\SublimeRepl\config` and edited the contents - the folder is a copy of the already existing folder *shell*.  There are two files that I needed to edit.  The first file is the `Default.sublime-commands` file.
In that line I just changed the the path to point to the second file, `Main.sublime-menu`.
In that file, there is an already existing section that shows the commands for all three OS's.  This is the exact line I put in for windows to get it to work: (my existing putty session is named **vagrant** and my pw is listed as vagrant here)

```
    "windows": ["plink", "-load", "vagrant", "-pw", "vagrant"]
```

And voila!